# 500 error when installing symfony2

Tags: installation, symfony, internal-server-error

I'm trying to install and configure Symfony2 on my server.
My website is on a shared hosting plateform therefore have limited access to root level, apache & php.ini files...

I downloaded then extracted symfony2 files on my dev environment:

```
 www/
 dev/
     symfony/
              app/
              bin/
              web/
              ...
```

When I navigate to http://dev.mydomain.com/symfony/web/config.php I get some recommendations:

1. Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended).
2. Upgrade your intl extension with a newer ICU version (4+).
3. Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.
4. Set magic_quotes_gpc to off in php.ini*.

Being on a shared hosting plateform I'm not allowed to modify/download the necessary files to fix those recommendations (which I believe shouldn't block the install).

I follow the link "Bypass configuration and go to the Welcome page" which sends me to http://dev.mydomain.com/symfony/web/app_dev.php/

The server throws a 500 Internal Server Error.

Any advice on how to fix that issue would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Which error exactly is it? It should have more specific details

Comment: If the error is displayed in a Symfony2 style error page, it is Symfony2 related. If it is a classic Apache error, you should check apache logs. `/var/log/apache2/error.log` on Mac & Linux generally.

Comment: By the way, are you sure there is a route defined for `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it happened to me I forgot to tell my FTP client to transfer also invisible file (.htaccess) OR permissions on /web folder are not correct

Comment: I updated the permissions on the .htaccess (755) file in the web folder and everything works fine now.
Thanks all for your responses.