# Symfony2 application returning 500 from both app.php and app_dev.php

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

I recently asked this question re. getting the production environment of my symfony app to work on my server.

It was working inside my domain.com/dev/ folder. Now I'm trying to move it to just domain.com/.

I first moved all the files to domain.com/ which means the app should be available at domain.com/web/, but in both prod and dev modes it returns a HTTP 500 error code. I tried deleting and clearing the cache with no results.

What could be happening? My server meets all the requirements for Symfony (app/check.php and web/config.php).

And lastly, should I be moving the app one step further back, and configuring my server to look for the 'web' folder as the web root rather than 'httpdocs'?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Error log is giving this:

```
Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/dev/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache
```

Comment: URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685907/500-error-when-installing-symfony2?rq=1

Comment: @diplex19 - Permissions to all my folders and files appear to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put your whole project under httpdocs. Only the web directory should be public.

Did you run composer install? `bootstrap.php.cache` is generated by one of the post-install handlers.

Comment: I've reconfigured my server so only my web folder is public. So now domain.com/app.php should work. I did install via composer initially and the bootstrapper.app.cache file does exist. What next?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue.

I reconfigured my server to use my web directory as the document root, manually cleared cache, then cleared via console with the --env=prod argument. Installed assets and it's working live perfectly. :)